# Example of World File

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, wgs84, maptiler

Does any body have an example of map world file, where it shows the input parameters including the latitude and longitude and the output world file.

I Google for world file, I found an explanation but I didn't see a full example.

Thanking you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this page:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file

It explains the format very well and it has also a World file example in UTM coordinate system. It is typically a text file with extension .wld and 6 lines such as:

```
32.0
0.0
0.0
-32.0
691200.0
4576000.0
```

You have on your question the tag "maptiler". If you want to [create Google Maps compatible tiles](http://www.maptiler.com/) with MapTiler then you don't need to define the World file, there are now also other options for how to assign location to an image. See http://www.maptiler.com/how-to/georeferencing/